# Связь между контейнерами

Tags: сеть, dns, docker

Каким образом можно назначить контейнерам статический ip и nameserver в /etc/resolv.conf в user-defined сети, для того чтобы привязать к нему днс имя и пользоваться для резолвинга между контейнерами?

Comment: для чего именно вам требуется «статический ip»?

Comment: для того чтобы привязать к нему днс имя и использоваться для резолвинга между контейнерами

Comment: Контейнеры так не работают (точнее, это вполне возможно, но это неправильный подход). Вам нужен SkyDNS, Consul или аналог.

Comment: Мне достаточно того, что ответил Александр Баракин. Особенно docker network --name это то, что я искал.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

для связи между контейнерами можно использовать:

- внутреннюю сеть docker-а
- [«связи» (links)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/#communication-across-links) между контейнерами
- начиная с версии 1.9 — [*docker networks*](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/)

### внутренняя сеть

наименее гибкое решение. при каждом перезапуске/пересоздании контейнер может получить другой внутренний адрес, соответственно, каждый раз может требоваться ручная корректировка связи имён и ip-адресов.

### docker links

при создании (комадна *create*) или запуске (*run*) контейнера можно указывать имя другого контейнера и имя, под которым тот будет доступен в новом контейнере:

```
$ docker run --link другой_контейнер:имя ...
```

благодаря этому в `/etc/hosts` создаваемого контейнера будет добавлена строчка примерно такого содержания:

```
ip-адрес-другого-контейнера имя
```

что позволит по данному имени обращаться к слинкованному контейнеру.

### docker networks

наиболее гибкое решение, но доступно только начианая с версии 1.9.

сначала с помощью команды *network create* надо описать сеть:

```
$ docker network create имя-сети
```

а затем при создании/запуске контейнеров указывать, что они должны быть «подключены» к этой сети под указанным именем. пример:

```
$ docker run --net=имя-сети --name=имя-контейнера ...
```

все контейнеры, подключенные к одной сети, будут «видеть» друг друга по присвоенным им именам.

---

## dns

ip-адреса nameserver-ов можно устанавливать для контейнера при его создании/запуске с помощью опции `--dns`:

```
$ docker run --dns ip-адрес ...
```