# Как правильно пробросить сервис sendmail внутрь docker контейнера

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

Изучаю докер. возник вопрос, если идеология заключается в "один сервис на один контейнер" то как эти сервисы линковать? например сервис отправки почты через функцию php mail(), которая работает с sendmail. каким образом заставить работать стандартный php mail() в контейнере без костылей ввиде supervisor и скриптов. Я так понимаю должен поднять отдельный контейнер с sendmail, но как его слинковать правильно?

Comment: Нужно понять, как вы планируете осуществлять связь. Традиционно в докере сетевые соединения используются, по-моему. Посему, жизнеспособным вариантом может быть поднятие SMTP-сервера в контейнере.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/519269/178576

Comment: или пробросить бридж, чтобы контейнеры видели друг друга. либо использовать activeMq.

Comment: Передавайте письма по smtp, никто и никогда не будет вам гарантировать наличие консольных утилит на том же сервере.

Comment: Ребят, мне нужно что бы все способы работали =)
Я делаю что-то типа хостинга (дальнейшая судьба проекта не понятна, пока цель просто поучиться). так вот клиент должен использовать любой желаемый способ. этой цели я пытаюсь достигнуть. очереди, smtp, mailgun и пр.  - это круто все. но нужно родной mail() завести ))

Объясните нубу, как сервис через сеть будет работать? он же вроде не вешается на порт. как тогда дотянуться до сервиса на соседнем контейнере?

Comment: еще раз - по smtp. в обход родного mail. он все равно будет скрывать под собой то же самое.

Comment: `mail`, встроенный в PHP, можно настроить, чтобы он слал письма по SMTP с заранее заданными учётными данными. SMTP-сервер ещё как вешается на порт.

Comment: @D-side А можно подробнее? я думал о таком, но не могу найти. PHP обязательно вызывает программу (sendmail или ему подобные). получается что должна быть программа, которая не является сервисом. и она должна отправлять письма на smtp. или я совсем запутался %)

Comment: \*жмёт на тормоза и трёт прошлую ерунду* Вместо `sendmail` можно подсунуть другую программу. [Скажем, `ssmtp`, которому демон не нужен и который просто шлёт почту по SMTP.](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/30#issuecomment-94952430)

Comment: А, ну секундочку, единственный ныне ответ примерно это и предлагает.

Comment: @D-side да, он верно написал, но я эту хрень не смог завести. в то время как ssmtp с полоборота завелся. Голосую что  ssmt + свой smtp на докере - решение проблемы!

Comment: Окей, перенёс это в ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немало обсуждений подобных проблем есть на гитхабе, и [одно из них](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/30#issuecomment-94952430) может вам подойти.

- Поставить в контейнер `ssmtp`
- Настроить `sendmail_path` в PHP на то, где `ssmtp` находится.

  ```
  sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/ssmtp -t
  ```
- Сконфигурировать `ssmtp` так, чтобы он указывал на любой SMTP-сервер.

  Можно в другой Docker-контейнер, можно наружу, а можно через контейнер-шлюз наружу (чтобы при случае можно было сменить способ отправки почты, ничего не выключая).

  Иными словами, куда угодно.

Answer (score 0):

Если не стоит задачи поставить что-то вроде exim или postfix, то проще всего слать письма через стороннюю почту поддерживающую SMTP, например Gmail или Yandex. Это достаточно просто реализуется через тот же msmtp. Достаточно установить в контейнере msmtp, создать конфиг с данными для подключения к ящику и прописать в php.ini `sendmail_path = /usr/bin/msmtp -t`. Как настроить msmtp можно прочитать тут https://websistent.com/how-to-use-msmtp-with-gmail-yahoo-and-php-mail/ или погуглить.
Более продвинутый вариант, это сделать отдельный контейнер под exim и в него засылать письма через тот же SMTP.