# пропала связь между контейнерами после перезапуска

Tags: docker

после одного из перезапусков (командой *restart*) одного из контейнеров пропала связь его с другим контейнером (установленная [опцией `--link`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/519379/178576) команд `run`/`create`).

теперь после перезапуска контейнера в `/etc/hosts` не добавляется строка вида

```
ip-адрес имя-связываемого-контейнера псевдоним
```

после изучения содержимого конфигурационных файлов контейнера (`/var/lib/docker/containers/идентификатор-контейнера/*.json`) ничего похожего на информацию о связывании контейнеров обнаружить не удалось.

версия docker: 1.9.1

где хранится эта информация и как её поправить, чтобы восстановить связь между контейнерами (без пересоздания контейнера)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> версия docker: 1.9.1

по крайней мере в этой версии (в других может быть иначе) связи между контейнерами описаны в sqlite-базе `/var/lib/docker/linkgraph.db`

перед манипуляциями имеет смысл сделать резервную копию этого файла.

связи хранятся в таблице `edge`:

```
sqlite> .schema edge
CREATE TABLE edge (
        "entity_id" text NOT NULL,
        "parent_id" text NULL,
        "name" text NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT "parent_fk" FOREIGN KEY ("parent_id") REFERENCES "entity" ("id"),
        CONSTRAINT "entity_fk" FOREIGN KEY ("entity_id") REFERENCES "entity" ("id")
        );
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "name_parent_ix" ON "edge" (parent_id, name);
```

- `entity_id` — идентификатор связываемого контейнера
- `parent_id` — идентификатор контейнера, в котором добавляется связь
- `name` — псевдоним связываемого контейнера, под которым он будет «виден»

текущие идентификаторы контейнеров можно увидеть в той же таблице:

```
sqlite> select * from edge where parent_id = 0;
ид-контейнера-1|0|container1
ид-контейнера-2|0|container2
```

чтобы добавить в `container2` связь с `container1`, т.е., чтобы при перезапуске `container2` в его файл `/etc/hosts` добавлялась строка вида:

```
ip-адрес-контейнера-1 container1 псевдоним
```

надо выполнить такую вставку:

```
sqlite> insert into edge (entity_id, parent_id, name)
   ...> values ("ид-контейнера-1", "ид-контейнера-2", "псевдоним");
```