# Использование одной СУБД для разных сервисов, запущенных в docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Добрый день.

Есть идея развернуть в докере на одном хосте два сервиса, использующих СУБД, которую также развернуть в докере.

Если решать поставленную задачу без докера, то на хосте был бы поднят один сервис СУБД, созданы две базы данных (по одной на каждый целевой сервис), два пользователя, по одному на каждую создаваемую базу, СУБД была бы выставлена наружу на соответствующем порту (3306 для MySQL и 5432 для postgres), а в целевых сервисах были бы произведены настройки для соединения с соответствующей базой данных.

Пытаюсь решить эту же задачу при помощи docker (конкретно при помощи docker-compose). Во всех примерах описывается поднятие в докере одной СУБД и одного сервиса, использующего эту СУБД через link. Создаётся впечатление, что в случае необходимости поднятия двух сервисов, использующих одну и ту же СУБД, для каждого сервиса нужно поднимать два экземпляра сервиса СУБД.

Конечно, можно при создании docker контейнера для сервиса СУБД прописать код, создающий базы данных и пользователей при помощи psql, но нигде в интернете не было найдено подобных примеров/описаний/рекомендаций, отчего сложилось впечатление, что я хочу странного и так никто не делает.

1. Правильно ли я понимаю, что поднятие нескольких сервисов одной и той же СУБД на одном хосте это норма?
2. И в противном случае, если всё же не следует создавать на одном хосте несколько сервисов СУБД, как следует решать данную задачу?

Прошу помочь найти ответы на эти вопросы.

Comment: [связь между контейнерами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/519379/178576)

Comment: если два Ваших сервиса не связаны между собой, то нормально использовать два различных контейнера с базой для каждого сервиса. Плюс этого решения - в случае чего - сервис легко перенести на другую машину (а это главный плюс докера).

Answer (score 1):

Если оба сервиса не зависят по бизнес-логике от друг от друга через БД, то лучше организовать два раздельных кластера(два различных docker-compose.yml).

В итоге на хосте будут работать два отдельных контейнера с СУБД.
Таким способом можно добиться отсутствие связности сервисов.

Для докера безразницы что в контейнере(сервер приложений, СУБД и т.д.), для него это все контейнеры, которые взаимодействуют между собой.

P.S. если есть ограничения по ресурсам на хосте, то вам никто не запрещает использовать одну БД на два сервиса(это поможет сэкономить на накладных ресурсах для подъема отдельной БД)

Comment: Но ведь в случае одной СУБД на оба сервера придётся запускать один контейнер с СУБД, а не два персональных контейнера СУБД, по одному на каждый сервер.

Comment: Да, все верно. Я описал случай, если сервисы не используют общие данные. В одном контейнере -один процесс СУБД.

Comment: По самому вопрос: 1 - да, это норма, потому что контейнер не раскрывает деталей содержимого. Общение между хост-контейнер, контейнер-контейнер осуществляется только через сетевой интерфейс.

Comment: На самом деле, вопрос больше о том, насколько пагубно для производительности держать на одном хосте два сервиса СУБД, той же Postgres, к примеру?
Если наличие двух сервисов СУБД на одном хосте нежелательно, получается, что для каждого сервиса надо выделять собственный хост.

Comment: Вопрос ресурсов сервера. Естественно, что каждый контейнер будет потреблять часть процессорного времени, оперативки и диска. Но практика показывает, что такие накладные ресурсы обычно малы по сравнению с неоптимизированными приложениями или sql запросами, когда запрос полностью нагружает процессор и диск.

Comment: Разделение СУБД на два контейнера, я считаю, будет более правильно. Системы не должны знать о существовании друг друга, если в этом нет необходимости. А объединение в один docker-compose file связывает разные приложения. Например, если будет изменение конфигурации в docker-compose file, придется опускать и поднимать все инстансы объявленные в этом файле, иначе изменение в конфигурации не подхватится