# Выполнить запрос на хост из контейнера

Tags: сеть, docker

Есть машина с ip 10.254.204.16

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На ней контейнеры. В контейнере с nginx проброшен порт 80 на приложение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из браузера при обращении по 10.254.204.16 я могу получить веб страничку.

А вот из контейера, который крутится на том же хосте - нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя пинги проходят.

Подскажите, как я могу из контейнера обратиться к хосту через его адрес?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: понял. но думал так наглядней.

Comment: 1. так где текст-то? 2. фактически вам же надо не к хосту, а к другому контейнеру обращаться. это очень распространённая [задача с целым рядом штатных решений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/519269/178576).

Comment: не совсем к другому контейнеру. это в этом случае контейнер находится на том же хосте, что и целевой контейнер. но в перспективе могут быть несколько экземпляров. так же в целом схема выглядит так что я обращаюсь не к ip хоста а dns серверу.  но я упростил потому что по dns имени ip резолвится и проблему уже с доступом по ip. Если располагаю точно такой же контейнер на другом хосте то проблем во взаимодействии нет.

Comment: и с доступом к неизолированным процессам проблем не будет. а вот между отдельно изолированными процессами надо налаживать связь – см. ссылку в пред. комментарии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте доступные сети:

```
docker network ls
```

Проверьте сеть контейнера c nginx:

```
docker inspect main_nginx_proxy -f "{{json .NetworkSettings.Networks }}
```

проверьте сеть второго контейнера

```
docker inspect mail_worker_microservice -f "{{json .NetworkSettings.Networks }}
```

Скорее всего они в разных сетях.

Отсоедините второй контейнер от его сети:

```
docker network disconnect networkname mail_worker_microservice
```

Добавьте второй контейнер в сеть nginx:

```
docker network connect networkname mail_worker_microservice
```

Проверьте изменения:

```
docker network inspect networkname -f "{{json .Containers }}"
```

Comment: Да я обьеденил их в одну сеть. И обращаюсь по имени контейнера.