# Достать значение из docker inspect в файл .env

Tags: docker, .env

Начал изучать Docker.
Создал образ который содержит 4 контейнера:

```
1. php:7.2-apache
2. mariadb
3. composer
4. phpmyadmin
```

В проекте есть файл `.env` в котором вписаны настройки подключения к бд: хост, юзер и тд. После запуска образа `docker-compose up -d` и выполнении команды `docker inspect mydb` Есть табличка с данными об этом контейнере.

```
 "NetworkSettings": {
            "Ports": {
                "3306/tcp": null
            },
            "Networks": {
                "sunrise_default": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "db",
                        "dd6ec2e0badb"
                    ],
                    "IPAddress": "172.19.0.2",
```

Проблема в том, что при перезапуске образа, `IPAddress` этого контейнера изменяется, и естественно подключение к бд не работает потому что меняется `ip`. Можно ли как нибудь достать это значение из dockera при запуска контейнера для того чтобы вставить в файл `.env`?? Либо есть какой нибудь другой способ для решения этой проблемы?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Связь между контейнерами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/519269/%d0%a1%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin на сколько я понял там идет через ручной запуск контейнеров, я же использую docker compose, и хотелось бы прописать все туда. Более менее понятно куда копать, но пока без результата)

Comment: ну так это ж всего лишь «конфигурялка». там же должно быть «всё очевидно и просто» (это сарказм — как и любая другая [дырявая абстракция](http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%94%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9), compose лишь маскирует и зартрудняет понимание происходящих процессов): https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам чаще всего не надо ориентироваться на что-то столь нестабильное как IP адрес контейнера. Это неправильно с точки зрения самой идеи Docker.

Если я правильно понял Вам необходимо обратится из одного контейнера в другой,
docker-compose для этого предоставляет функционал внутреннего DNS, каждый контейнер будет доступен другим по имени сервиса в файле docker-compose
В представленном случае это имя **"db"**