# Можно ли из одного контейнера узнать о состоянии других контейнеров?

Tags: docker

Например есть 3 запущенных контейнера.
В первом контейнера нужно вывести информацию о том работают ли 2 других. Как это проверить?

Comment: [Связь между контейнерами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/519269/178576)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно только проверить состояние контейнеров, то обычно для этих целей создают HealthCheck и потом уже в другом контейнере делают обычный http запрос.

Но если такой возможности нет или нужно именно управлять контейнерами, то можно получить доступ к Docker Daemon (через монтирование docker сокета):

```
docker run --rm --name test -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ubuntu
```

И уже внутри можно установить `apt-get install docker.io` и команды докера будут доступны (например, `docker ps -a`), таким же способом получают доступ тулзы/UI для управления докером, например: [portainer.io](https://www.portainer.io/installation/). Но, я бы, все же, такие большие возможности контейнеру не давал бы.